# how to insert form query into $html = file_get_contents_curl();

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, file-get-contents

Hi i'm trying to use a form submission data in `file_get_contents_curl()`

i want to make a form where you submit an url and get to look up meta tags on that website

here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit">
</form></center>

<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl($_POST["test"];); // the submitted url should go here
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'title')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}


echo '<br/><br/>';
echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords". '<br/><br/>';
?>
```

when i manually enter address everything works great eg.

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl('skynews.com');
```

but this doesn't work at all:

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl($_POST["test"];);
```

How do i call on this variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, i finally figured it out!

i had to add a variable first

```
<?php $address = $_POST["test"];?>
```

and

```
$html = file_get_contents_curl($address);
```

works great

Comment: This surely is not the problem, as it's redundant to use an extra variable in this case. Probably the error was/is the surplus `;` here: `$html = file_get_contents_curl($_POST["test"];);` make that: `$html = file_get_contents_curl($_POST["test"]);`